# Perturbation theory with degenerate and non-degenerate states (at the same time)

Tags: quantum-mechanics, perturbation-theory

In the time independent perturbation theory, the perturbed wavefunction is [1]:
$$ \left|n^{(1)}\right> = \sum_{k\neq n} \frac{\left<k^{(0)}\right|V\left|n^{(0)}\right>}{E_n^{(0)}-E_k^{(0)}}\left|k^{(0)}\right>$$
However, if the $\left|n^{(0)}\right>$ is degenerate, the denominator would become zero and the term would diverge. I found this note [2] using an approximation that perturbation to a degenerate state only mixes those states which are degenerate. So, the degenerate subspace can be treated separately using degenerate perturbation theory. But this approximation comes without justification. I don't understand why this can be true. I found another note from MIT [3]. In the section 11.1.2, it derives that, in the projection of degenerate subspace, the perturbation to a degenerate state only mixes other degenerate state. But it's not clear that the contribution from the outside of the degenerate subspace is negligible.

My question is: Is it true that perturbation to a degenerate state only mixes those states which are degenerate? Why is it?

Reference 
[1] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perturbation_theory_(quantum_mechanics)   
[2] https://www2.ph.ed.ac.uk/~gja/qp/qp3.pdf 
[3] https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/nuclear-engineering/22-51-quantum-theory-of-radiation-interactions-fall-2012/lecture-notes/MIT22_51F12_Ch11.pdf

Comment: General tip: Check the right margin for duplicate questions.